# Mute microphone voip

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, voip, avaudiosession

I use the twilio SDK for voip and I would like to mute "my" microphone and demute it when I pressed a button.

A this point I tried :

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                                             error:nil];
```

and

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
```

With both of them I got this error

> Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be
>   stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

and because the error I can't relaunch the audio session/"stream" with :

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

any clue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To mute "yourself" you can direclty use the mute property in your connection.
The [twilio SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios)'ll do the rest.

```
//the mute stated can be applied if the state is not TCConnectionStateConnected
        if(self.connection.state == TCConnectionStateConnected){
            self.connection.muted = !self.connection.isMuted;
        }
```